# AVFoundation- .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient runs after CXCallObserver call.hasEnded (call disconnection) is called

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, callkit

I'm using `AVFoundation` for video recording. I also use the `CXCallObserverDelegate` to listen to when a phone call is disconnected.

1. I go to the background
2. I make a phone call
3. While the phone call is active I bring the app back to the foreground and press the button to modally present the vc that contains `AVFoundation`
4. Once the vc is on scene and because I'm currently on a phone call the `.audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient` gets called and I stop the `capture session`
5. Once the phone call is disconnected then `CXCallObserver call.hasEnded` is called and I restart the `capture session`. The `.sessionInterruptionEnded` also gets called but this isn't causing the issue.
6. **This is where the problem occurs.** Once `call.hasEnded` is called then `.audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient` gets called **again**. Since the code to stop the capture session is in there this results in capture session stopping again

In step 6 why does `.audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient` get called again **after** the call has been disconnected?

```
func sessionWasInterrupted(notification: NSNotification) {

    let reasonIntegerValue = userInfoValue.integerValue,
    let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonIntegerValue) {

        case .audioDeviceInUseByAnotherClient:

            stopCaptureSession()
        }
    }
}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("-----Capture session interruption ended")

    restartCaptureSession()
}

func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {

    if call.hasEnded == true {
        print("\nCXCallState :Disconnected")

        restartCaptureSession()
    }

    if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {
        print("\nCXCallState : Connected")

        // *** THIS NEVER GETS CALLED IN THIS SCENARIO ***
    }
}

fileprivate func stopCaptureSession() {

    if captureSession.isRunning {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self?.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
                self?.previewLayer = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func restartCaptureSession() {

    if !captureSession.isRunning {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self?.captureSession.startRunning()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {

                if let safeSelf = self {

                    if safeSelf.previewLayer == nil {

                        self?.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self!.captureSession)
                        self?.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                        guard let previewLayer = self?.previewLayer else { return }
                        previewLayer.frame = self!.containerViewForPreviewLayer.bounds
                        self?.containerViewForPreviewLayer.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `CXCallObserverDelegate`? Why not only observe `AVCaptureSession` interruptions? And by the way, your messing up with the `DispatchQueue`s. I highly suggest you to take a deeper look at the documentation, there's also a sample code to get started https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app